# How can I find a performance of Mozart's Piano Concerto No. 20 in D minor?

Tags: online-resources, where-on-earth, music

Listening to Mozart's Piano Concerto No. 20 in D minor is one of my favourite pieces to program against. Whenever I need to do some serious programming I just search for some performances on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiHKJeoXdNM) and code away.

It just struck me that although it is one of my favourite pieces, I never have seen an actual performance live. Is there an online resource (similar to [Operabase](http://operabase.com/)), where you can search for a given concerto being performed somewhere in the world? I have search a bit, but usually the search options are concert hall driven. Here I want to travel somewhere the piece is actually being performed soon.

Comment: Won't the answer to this change all the time, depending on which orchestra might be playing it in any given season?

Comment: @flimzy that is why I added the Operabase example. It is about finding out where to go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bachtrack is doing that for you. Looking for the concert reveals that the [Piano Concerto No. 20 in D minor](http://bachtrack.com/work/piano-concerto-no-20-in-d-minor-k466-mozart) is currently performed by the [Pittsburgh Symphony Orchestra](http://bachtrack.com/22/291/view/167223) and the [Austin Symphony Orchestra](http://bachtrack.com/22/291/view/174159).

You can even [read reviews](http://bachtrack.com/find-reviews/work=8157) of this concert of all known past performances.